# How to perform basic Auth in Lua

Tags: lua

I have the following partial lua script.

```
local config_string = [===[

]===]

local config = LuaConfig:new(config_string)
local request = LuaHttpRequest:new(config, "HTTP")

local username = "sss"
local password = "xxx"


request:set_header("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")
request:set_header("Accept","application/json")

request:set_body("{\"RecordTitle\": { \"Value\": \"test vinay 344\"  }, \"RecordRecordType\": \"2\", \"Fields\": { \"RoadSurface\" { \"Value\": \"smooth\" } } }")

request:set_url("http://ddddddd/CMServiceAPI/Record")
```

How do i perform basic Auth?

Comment: How do you define "basic auth"?

Comment: username and password authentication over web request.

Comment: How does the *server* expect the authentication to work? Normally you can just add username and password to the URL like `http(s)://<user>:<password>@domain.tld/some/route`, but not every server necessarily supports that.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know which library you use, but something like this:

```
local username = "sss"
local password = "xxx"

local mime = require("mime")

request:set_header("authentication", "Basic " .. (mime.b64(username ..":" .. password)) )
request:set_header("content-type", "application/json" )
```

and at the end use a POST request